# Parquet files written from Spark Dataframe appear corrupted

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am writing data to Parquet files using Spark, reading data output from AWS Kinesis in an hourly fashion based upon AWS Kinesis hourly partitions.

When writing, I partition the data output by `year/month/day/hour/eventType`, and then append & save to S3:

```
fooDf
  .withColumn("timestamp_new", (col("timestamp").cast("timestamp")))
  .drop("timestamp")
  .withColumnRenamed("timestamp_new", "timestamp")
  .withColumn("year", year(col("timestamp")))
  .withColumn("month", month(col("timestamp")))
  .withColumn("day", dayofmonth(col("timestamp")))
  .withColumn("hour", hour(col("timestamp")))
  .write
  .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .partitionBy("year", "month", "day", "hour", "eventType")
  .parquet("s3://foo/bar/foobar")
```

, but the problem arises when reading, I get incompatible data types, even though Parquet should handle schema updates.  The issue is:

```
Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2041)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2029)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2028)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2028)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2262)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2211)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2200)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:777)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:365)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3383)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2544)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2758)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:745)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:704)
  ... 85 elided
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: Encounter error while reading parquet files. One possible cause: Parquet column cannot be converted in the corresponding files. Details:
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:193)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
  ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 0 in block -1 in file s3://foo/bar/foobar/year=2019/month=9/day=5/hour=22/eventType=barbarbar/part-rawr-c000.snappy.parquet
  at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:251)
  at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(ParquetRecordReader.java:207)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:181)
  ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Expected instance of group converter but got "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRowConverter$ParquetStringConverter"
  at org.apache.parquet.io.api.Converter.asGroupConverter(Converter.java:34)
  at org.apache.parquet.io.RecordReaderImplementation.<init>(RecordReaderImplementation.java:267)
  at org.apache.parquet.io.MessageColumnIO$1.visit(MessageColumnIO.java:147)
  at org.apache.parquet.io.MessageColumnIO$1.visit(MessageColumnIO.java:109)
  at org.apache.parquet.filter2.compat.FilterCompat$NoOpFilter.accept(FilterCompat.java:165)
  at org.apache.parquet.io.MessageColumnIO.getRecordReader(MessageColumnIO.java:109)
  at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.checkRead(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:137)
  at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:222)
  ... 26 more
```

Comment: Try loading single file which is complaining ie s3://foo/bar/foobar/year=2019/month=9/day=5/hour=22/event=barbarbar/part-rawr-c000.snappy.parquet . And see whether it load data or not. Looks like that file is corrupted.

Comment: @Prateek - it loads fine :).

Comment: what is the SaveMode in source ? I suspect  there is some data type mismatch.  either in failed location or in other files. it will be tedious process but you have to load couple of files and check schema type.

Comment: @Prateek - when I load all data at once (instead of by partition), and write, it works fine.  When I load each folder and write to the same destination with mode "append" it is failing.

Comment: @EricMeadows did you happen to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For some similar situations where written datatypes fail to be read, setting `spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat` to `True` may fix.

### Details:

Spark writes records in Parquet format while processing the raw data, but Hive fails to read them due to incompatible conventions. This happens when some datatypes fail to be mapped between Spark and Hive.

Sources:

- https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/parquet/ParquetSchemaConverter.scala
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49726124/3100587

Answer (score -1):

This is a common problem as while reading Spark can not determine data type for `eventType` (e.g `event=barbarbar`)

in spark-submit or inside your code, set following before `reading` the file
`spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled", "false")`

or read it with a Schema.

Comment: I tried this, but I still get the same item:  `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Expected instance of group converter but got "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRowConverter$ParquetStringConverter"`

Comment: @EricMeadows , How come you are partitioning by column 'eventType' `.partitionBy("year", "month", "day", "hour", "eventType")` but stacktrace shows a path => `Caused by: org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 0 in block -1 in file s3://foo/bar/foobar/year=2019/month=9/day=5/hour=22/event=barbarbar/part-rawr-c000.snappy.parquet` e.g `event=barbarbar` ? if that partition column name is messed up, how could Spark dataframe reader read it from higher level s3 prefixes ?

Comment: when writing, I parsing Kinesis Streams, and using the column `eventType`, which is not corrupted and being properly read into the DF, and I am then using it to partition.  When examining that file, it appears to be fine & not corrupted.

Comment: why there is an s3 prefix as `event=<...>` , if you are partitioning by `eventType`, the prefix should be `eventType=<...>` !

Comment: I changed some of the output because of sensitive information.  I accidentally used `event` and `eventType =` interchangeably.

Comment: So, change them back to a `single` column name either `eventType` or `event` and your problem will be solved.

Comment: you missed this.  It's a single column name - I mistyped in the original question.  It is not a mismatch - the column is consistent across all parquet files.  I updated the question.