# AWS Athena - error - Can not read value at 0 in block 0 in file s3://

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I can read data from S3 location using Spark and Glue without issues but when trying to read with Athena for the same table - getting error when running `select * from mytable limit 10;`

```
HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Can not read value at 0 in block 0 in file


s3://.../part-00073-123-926b-456-c000.snappy.parquet
```

What could be the issue and how to fix it?

I tried with:
`MSCK REPAIR TABLE mytable;`

That did not help (getting the same error).

Table create statement is:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `mytable`(
co1 ..,
col2 ..
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://.../../'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER'='raw_1', 
  'averageRecordSize'='105', 
  'classification'='parquet', 
  'compressionType'='none', 
  'objectCount'='155', 
  'recordCount'='33459791', 
  'sizeKey'='1738251189', 
  'typeOfData'='file')
```

Comment: Can you provide table definition, i.e. `SHOW CREATE TABLE you_table_name`, please?

Comment: Provided in a question.

Comment: It seems to me that you problem relates to different parquet conventions used in Hive and Spark, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49726124/6147064) for more info. How the files on S3 were created? Also, I see that you used Glue Crawler to define table. Do you know what type of values to expect in your colummns? You removed types of columns, so can't tell for sure, but have you tried what is proposed in [this post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=275809&tstart=0&messageID=836262#836262)

Comment: in the table defintion 'compressionType'='none' while the name of the file has snappy  in it. Change one or the other.