# Can not read value at 0 in block -1 in file

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

Suppose I have an external partitioned table in Hive. There are different columns and column A with *decimal(18, 2)* type. I am writing data via Spark application into this table, and data stored as parquet.
When I am trying to execute `SELECT * FROM table` or `SELECT A from table` in Hive I get

`parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 0 in block -1 in file <hdfs path>`

But I am able to select all non-decimal columns from this table in Hive.

Also I am able to read parquet file via Spark and its schema is matching with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statement result.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37829334/parquet-io-parquetdecodingexception-can-not-read-value-at-0-in-block-1-in-file) is similar problem and solution is to set *spark.sql.writeLegacyFormat = true*, but I've already had this property with *true* value.

When I've increased precision for decimal column to 28, I got rid of this error.

So I am wondering why selecting decimal column with precision <= 18 produced ParquetDecodingException, and selecting column with precision > 18 not. Are there other ways to solve this problem?